# Polynomial Functions and Their Graphs - Seeking Help for a Deeper Understanding

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Match the the polynomial function with one of the graphs I - IV. Give reasons for your choice.

1) P(x) = x(x^2-4)

I chose number III because it reminded me of a power function raised to the 3rd power

2) R(x) = -x^5 + 5x^3 -4x

I chose V (FIVE) because it had a leading coefficient of -1 and had a odd power. I also counted the maximum and minimum points, although they do not add up to 5; however, I am under the understanding that does not matter. Yet, I am still unsure of the way you calculate the maximum or minimums. (some insight will be greatly appreciated)

3) T(x) = x^4 +2x^3

I chose II since the leading coefficient is positive and the degree is positive.

My main question is do I determine which function belongs to which graph by:

A) Counting the amount of times the function crosses the x axis and comparing that with the function's degree? [image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in most cases: yes. A polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ roots assuming $n\gt0$. If you want to prove this, use the fact that if $\alpha$ is the root of a polynomial $\mathcal O(x)$ then there exist only one polynomial $\mathcal P(x)$ such that $\mathcal O(x)=(x-\alpha)\cdot\mathcal P(x)$.

I hope this helps. 
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.